# Method not returning correct values for an array. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I'm trying to use a method to calculate y for all values between 1 and x of a given x for straight lines.

I want the values for y to be placed in an array and returned to the main method. When I run my program all values in the array are 0; where have I gone wrong?

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            int n=0;
            int k=0;
            int m=0;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Value of x: ");
            n = in.nextInt();

            int line[] = new int [n];
            System.out.println("value of k: ");
            k = in.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Value of m: ");
            m = in.nextInt();

            calcLine(n,k,m);
            for(int i = 0; i < line.length; i++){ 
                System.out.println(line[i]);  
            }
        }

    public static int[] calcLine(int n, int k, int m)
    {
        int[] line = new int[n];

        for (int i=0; i<line.length;i++){
            line[i] = (int) (k * i + m);
        }

        return line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `main` method has a different array called `line` than the one your `calcLine` method populates.

You should assign the returned array of your `calcLine` method to the `line` variable of your `main` method :

```
line = calcLine(n,k,m);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should assign calcLine(n,k,m); to line

Answer (score 0):

The `line` in your `calcLine` method and the one in your `main` method are completely separate.  You need to assign the value of line to the return value of the `calcLine` function.

Get rid of the declaration of line in main (`int line[] = new int [n];`) and change the method call line to:

`int line[] = calcLine(n,k,m);`

Answer (score 0):

Your calcLine method is using a local variable (line) and performing all calculations in it. Then you return this variable, but in the code of your main function it is not stored anywhere.

Replace the line

```
calcLine(n,k,m);
```

with

```
line = calcLine(n,k,m);
```

Local variables are only alive in the scope where declared. This "line" inside calcLine is not the same "line" in the main caller function. When you return it, you must store the result of calcLine in line and then use it.